# How is the default LED blinking implemented on the beaglebone black

Tags: embedded-linux, startup, beagleboneblack

Are there any beaglebone or embedded linux experts here? 
A general question on something I can't understand regarding the board when it is powered-on initially.

The LEDs have a default blinking sequence. It is of course possible to change the behavior of the LEDs after startup by software, but on start-up , how is this default blinking sequence implemented?, and how could this be modified to be different on startup for example?

Is this a process that gets started when Debian starts up?
If so, I can't see it when I type command "ps".
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### This answer relates to an earlier version of this question which asked about the flashing LED pattern of "flasher images"

Please have a look at the [official repository for boot scripts, which include emmc flasher scripts](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/boot-scripts/tree/master/tools/eMMC)

Note the readme, conveniently printed out at the bottom of the directory listing. It explains which of the scripts are currently in use.

Also note, that a lot of the code is shared by 'sourcing' `functions.sh` from within the same directory

Answer (score 0):

The LED blinking or *"flashing"* (in Linux) can easily be specified as a property in the Device Tree.
Two common modes are:

```
 "heartbeat" - LED "double" flashes at a load average based rate
 "timer" - LED flashes at a fixed, configurable rate
```

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/leds/common.txt